# PROPAGATION_REQUIRED transaction attribute in spring?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-transactions

In first case study given at http://www.vermatech.com/code/SpringTransactionExamples.html,
program is calling two methods i.e.

```
testModel.deleteAllCountries();
testModel.initializeCountries();
```

where initializeCountries throws runtime exception. For both methods' transaction definition attribute is PROPAGATION_REQUIRED. Still transaction under deleteAllCountries
method gets committed but transaction under initializeCountries are rolled back(as per the logs given in the same case study).

As per PROPAGATION_REQUIRED definition is that it Support a current transaction; create a new one if none exists. So my question here is transaction under  initializeCountries method
should support the transaction under deleteAllCountries method. I mean both method should be treated as single transaction. As per my understanding either complete transaction should be committed  or rolled back? Not sure how come logs are treating them separately.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"Propagation required" is defined as

> Support a current transaction, create a new one if none exists.

In your case above the deleteAllCountries method executes in a transaction and commits. There is no current transaction when initializeCountries is called, so it executes in a second transaction, and rolling it back has no effect on the changes made by the first method.

Propagation applies to nested method calls, not to successive ones. If you look at [the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-propagation):

> When the propagation setting is PROPAGATION_REQUIRED, a logical
>   transaction scope is created for each method upon which the setting is
>   applied. Each such logical transaction scope can determine
>   rollback-only status individually, with an outer transaction scope
>   being logically independent from the inner transaction scope. Of
>   course, in case of standard PROPAGATION_REQUIRED behavior, all these
>   scopes will be mapped to the same physical transaction. So a
>   rollback-only marker set in the inner transaction scope does affect
>   the outer transaction's chance to actually commit (as you would expect
>   it to).
>
> However, in the case where an inner transaction scope sets the
>   rollback-only marker, the outer transaction has not decided on the
>   rollback itself, and so the rollback (silently triggered by the inner
>   transaction scope) is unexpected. A corresponding
>   UnexpectedRollbackException is thrown at that point. This is expected
>   behavior so that the caller of a transaction can never be misled to
>   assume that a commit was performed when it really was not. So if an
>   inner transaction (of which the outer caller is not aware) silently
>   marks a transaction as rollback-only, the outer caller still calls
>   commit. The outer caller needs to receive an
>   UnexpectedRollbackException to indicate clearly that a rollback was
>   performed instead.

then you can see all of this is about inner- and outer-, none of it mentions successive calls. In your case the call to deleteAllCountries is the outermost transactional method, so when it finishes successfully then Spring commits the transaction immediately. Then your call to initializeCountries has to be executed within a separate transaction, where it is the outermost method.

Your assumption seems to be that Spring will hold the transaction open after the first method finishes, but that's not how it works. In order to get the effect you want, you could create another method on testModel that wraps the calls to deleteAllCountries and initializeCountries, make that method transactional and give it the attribute PROPAGATION_REQUIRED. That way a rollback of the second method will cause the first method's changes to be rolled back too, because the wrapping method is grouping them together. Otherwise nothing is telling Spring these things should be part of the same transaction.

Comment: Thanks Nathan .But got some more question after going thru the link. There are two statements. Statement1 -Each such logical transaction scope can determine rollback-only status individually, with an outer transaction scope being logically independent from the inner transaction scope. Statement2 -Of course, in case of standard PROPAGATION_REQUIRED behavior, all these scopes will be mapped to the same physical transaction. So a rollback-only marker set in the inner transaction scope does affect the outer transaction's chance to actually commit (as you would expect it to).

Comment: In statement1 which one is outer and which one is inner transaction. In Statemt2:- which one is same physical transaction here

Comment: @Mohit: the point is that neither one is outer or inner, it's not applicable.

Comment: Actually  nathan i am trying to get the meaning of statement "However, in the case where an inner transaction scope sets the rollback-only marker, the outer transaction has not decided on the rollback itself, and so the rollback (silently triggered by the inner transaction scope) is unexpected. A corresponding UnexpectedRollbackException is thrown at that point." Sorry but can you help me to  understand with some brief example with which one is inner and outer transaction terms? Thanks in advance

Comment: @mohit: In my proposed fix the wrapper method is outer, the existing methods are inner. but let's see what other answers come up, maybe somebody can explain it better than me. there are some very solid experts who should see this.